# Tell django to search app's template subfolders

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following folder structure for the templates on my django app:

```
templates/
   app/
      model1/
         model1_form.html
      model2/ 
         model2_form.html
```

Suppose I'm using model1 and a generic ListView, right now it only searches at templates/app/model1_form.html. Is there anyway I can tell django he should also search the app/ subfolders? I don't want to have to set the template name and path manually (`template_name="templates/app/model1/model1_form.html"`).

At settings.py I have:

```
import os.path
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    BASE_PATH+'/templates/',
)
```

This is my view:

```
class HousesListView(ListView):
    model = House
    context_object_name = "house_list"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` to `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` (if it's not already).

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Then, change your folder structure such that you have a "templates" folder in the app directory:

```
- <project_root>
    - app
        - templates
            - model1
            - model2
```

Or to properly namespace the models so they don't clash with other app names accidentally:

```
- <project_root>
    - app
        - templates
            - app
                - model1
                - model2
```

Comment: Check Bob Vork's answer for Django 1.8+

Answer (score 26):

The other answers were correct at the time, but for anyone coming across this now, this is how this is done in Django 1.8+

By default, Django now looks in app folders for templates. This is indicated by `'APP_DIRS': True,` in the `TEMPLATES` setting like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    ...
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    ...
  },
]
```

As the other answers indicate, you should still use `appname/templates/appname/model1_form.html` to namespace the templates

( more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something in the box titled 'template namespacing')

Final check: make sure the app you're using is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple, as that was the problem I was having.

Comment: Well done. "make sure the app you're using is in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple"

Answer (score 1):

I think to use templates from subfolders generally you either have to:

1. Manually give the template path as `subdir/template.html`
   eg. render_to_response('sub/dir/template.html') or template_name='...'
2. Define all the subfolders in the `TEMPLATE_DIRS`
   eg.

   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       BASE_PATH+'/templates/',
       BASE_PATH+'/templates/app',
       BASE_PATH+'/templates/app/model1',
   )

   But because Generic Views except templates to be found in app_name/template.html,
   you would have to move your templates to add `/path/to/templates/app/model1` to your TEMPLATE_DIRS, and move your templates to `templates/your_app/model/your_app/model_template.html`, which is little bit awkward.

Comment: I tried number 2, putting "templates/app/model1" at the TEMPLATE_DIR but this makes django search at "templates/app/model1/app/model1_form.html". What do you mean with number 1?

Comment: @Clash Did you give the absolute paths, or relative to your "templates-root"?   By 1. I meant to call the templates with the full path, which you didn't want to do?

Comment: what do you mean use "model/template.html"?

Comment: Where are you talking about "giving absolute paths"? The ListView already searches automatically at app/model_list.html. I have edited the original post to clarify what my settings has and how my view looks like.

Comment: @Clash eg. render_to_response("model1/model1_form.html"). By absolute path I mean giving full path for all the subfolders.

Comment: I'm using a class based view, so I don't even have to set the template name. Take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/. I have just checked and it's like if I had done render_to_response("app/model1_form.html"). So I guess there's no smart way around this?

Comment: @clash Seems that overriding the default `template_name` is the only way. (Unless you do templates/model1/your_app/model1.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Django 2.0, it's not even necessary to change anything in the `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`.
The only requirement is to add `appname.apps.AppnameConfig` (e.g. *catalog.apps.CatalogConfig* for an app named 'catalog') to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list, then django will look under appname/templates when it searches for templates.